# Make an ajax request based on the output from another ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

What I am doing now is, I am making an Jquery ajax call whenever a user clicks a button and If I get a particular output from this call, say **12345**, then I need to make another ajax call. I can easily do that by making the second ajax call inside the **success** callback, but I believe this is not a nice way to get things done.
       So I tried different methods to implement this. But the thing is, my two ajax calls doesn't depend on each other. What I mean is, I don't need to pass data from **ajax 1** to **ajax2**. I need to make the second ajax call only if I receive an output, **12345** from my first call. So what I did is

```
var first_call= ajax_call_1;
ajax_call_1.done(function(data)
{
    if(data==='1234')
    {
         // call a function which will perform the second ajax call
    }
    else
    {
         // do nothing
    }
});
```

So my question is, Is there any other way to implement this? I mean a better way to do this? I am new to **jquery deferred object and promise**. I am going through the documentation now. I appreciate all the help I get.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/file',
            type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
            dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
            data: {param1: 'value1'},
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            if (data==='1234') {
                nextAjax(data);
            }
        })      

        function nextAjax(DataFromFirstAjax) {
            console.log(DataFromFirstAjax);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/path/to/file',
                type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
                dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
                data: {param1: 'value1'},
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log('done!');
            })
        }

    });
```

Try this. When first ajax done do function nextAjax(DataFromFirstAjax); with next ajax and data

Answer (score 0):

> I need to make the second ajax call only if I receive an output, 12345 from my first call

Which certainly means that they depend on each other. At least one bit of information (whether the call is to be made) is passed.

> Is there any other way to implement this? I mean a better way to do this?

Yes. You can (and should) use the `.then()` method to chain asynchronous functions. This will lead to less nesting as well.

```
$.ajax({…}) // first call
.then(function(data) { // results of first call
    if (data == 12345)
        return $.ajax({…}) // second call
//      ^^^^^^ always return promises from functions that do something asynchronous
    else return data; // maybe pass through first data (omit if you don't need it)
}) // a promise that resolves after the second ajax call (or immediately if none is made)
.then(function(data) { // results of second call, or passed through values
    console.log("one or two calls are done");
});
```

Comment: If you need to make the second call only if the first was successful, use the `jqXHR.done(function() {})`.

Comment: What do you mean by powerful? It's all about necessity. `done` receives the same parameters that `then`. `done(function() {})` is exactly the same as `then(function() {}, null)`, isn't it?

Comment: @MarcosLima: But it returns something else. Have a closer look at my answer.

Comment: @Bergi :  Thank you for your help. I have tried your method. But after returning promises from second call, I am getting the output of first call inside then(function(data)) . I am not passing through  the first data . You can view the sample using this link https://jsfiddle.net/exawxbp1/

Comment: @user2766829: Are you sure you have used `then` not `done`? I am certain that the `data` in the second callback is the result of the second ajax call (or `undefined` if your first callback didn't return anything). Can you maybe make a demo that show the non-working code? Edit: thanks for the fiddle, but unfortunately that throws runtime exceptions.

Comment: @Bergi: Sorry about that. I just want to show you how I have implemented the chaining. Let me take a look at  the fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, but that chaining should work, and for certain not pass through the results of the first callback implicitly (or are you using a very old jQuery version?).

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I am using jQuery v1.7.1. May be its due to that

Comment: Then you'd need to use `pipe` instead of `then`, see also [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/). But also consider upgrading.